# java regex matching &[text(text - text text) !text]

Tags: java, regex

I am currently working on creating a regex to split out all occurrences of Strings that match the following format: `&[text(text - text text) !text]`. Here text can be any char really. and the spacing is important. The text will be listed as shown.

I have tried the following regex but I cannot seem to get it to work:

```
&\\[([^\\]]*)\\]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want to extract `text` with split function with that pattern?

Comment: No, I am trying to replace text matching that pattern.

Comment: So the below answers should work for you

Comment: your purpose is not clean enough to me, if you want to extract them the below answers are correct, otherwise clarify you question

Answer (score 1):

You replace `text` with `\w+` to capture 1 or more word characters.
Assuming everything else was a literal, the following regular expression should work:

`&\[\w+\(\w+ - \w+ \w+\) !\w+\]`

You could also use `[a-zA-Z]` in place of `\w` if you would like. It is sometimes easier to understand since it explicitly describes the characters to match, `a-z` and `A-Z` inclusive.

`&\[[a-zA-Z]+\([a-zA-Z]+ - [a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+\) ![a-zA-Z]+\]`

And for one character only, remove the `+`

`&\[\w\(\w - \w \w\) !\w\]`

`&\[[a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z] - [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z]\) ![a-zA-Z]\]`

P.S - I cant remember if `-`, `&`, or `!` are coutned as regex symbols and if they are you can make them literals by using `\-`, `\&`, or `\!`.

P.P.S - In java you have to escape `\` so `\w` becomes `\\w` in a string.

Comment: You have to escape the `(` and `)` characters as well.

Comment: It still is not working, I am trying to replace all of the text matching the criteria as follows: text.replaceAll("&\\[\\w+\\(\\w+ - \\w+ \\w+\\) !\\w+\\]","<?>") with strings that look like: this &[RECNUM !##0000] test &[SUM(Patron - Account Balance) !#,##0.00]. The regex should ignore the first macro and replace the second and it is not replacing any of the text. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract `text` as groups to work with them after:

```
&\\[(\\w+)\\((\w+)\\s\\-\\s(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)\\)\\s!(\\w+)]
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/sOXvtt/1)